# Where can I download Bootcamp drivers for Windows 8 Macbook1,1?

Tags: bootcamp, driver, windows

I have been looking for Windows 8 Boot Camp drivers for my first generation MacBook Pro. Where will I be able to find said drivers?

Comment: This guide entitled how to Install Windows 8 On Your Mac maybe of assistance http://www.labnol.org/software/install-windows-8-on-mac-bootcamp/20923/

Comment: This website: http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p682/download-bootcamp-drivers has Boot Camp drivers for Windows 7/8 if the Assistant won't download them properly.

Comment: @FaizSaleem I've seen the link before. It has the drivers for practically every apple machine EXCEPT Macbook 1,1. Thats the problem. Thanks to everyone though for your efforts to help.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark as answer, to help others with same questions too.

Comment: @namehere Boot Camp 5 now officially supports Windows 8 (64 bit)

Comment: @namehere If one of the given answers has helped you download the drivers you require - don't forget to accept one

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not support this officially, but I've used the windows 7 one and installed Windows 8 without any problem.

I can start my Windows bootcamp without any issue and Windows 8 runs like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official Boot Camp support page:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638

**Boot Camp 5** adds support for Windows 8 (64-bit) and the new drivers support both Windows 7 (64-bit) and Windows 8 (64-bit). Unfortunately, Boot Camp 5 doesn’t support 32-bit Windows 7 and Windows 8.

So, Mac users have no option but to install 64-bit Windows using Boot Camp. However, the previous version (v4.0) of Boot Camp supports 32-bit Windows 7.

The support page also notes that Boot Camp supports upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8, provided that you install Boot Camp 5.0 drivers on your Windows 7 machine before upgrading to Windows 8. If your Mac comes with Fusion Drive, it turns out that Boot Camp Assistant will help you install Windows on hard disk drive, not the Flash drive even if you have sufficient free space. Also note that Boot Camp doesn’t support installing Windows on external hard drive.

The download size of Boot Camp drivers (5.0.5033) is 553.62 MB and supports following Mac models:

- MacBook Air, mid 2011 or later
- MacBook Pro, mid 2010 or later (MacBook Pro 13 inch mid 2010 isn’t support)
- Mac Pro, early 2009 or later
- Mac mini, mid 2011 or later
- iMac, mid 2010 or later

Drivers for Boot Camp 5:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638

Boot Camp 5 Frequently asked questions:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5639

Answer (score 1):

Apple's latest version of Bootcamp 5.0 Clearly states supports for both 64x versions of Windows 7 & 8.  I cannot verify this as I am downloading the information  now, but this is a change in verbiage.  They no longer state that Windows 7 is required to Install Bootcamp.

Answer (score 0):

It's true there's no official support, but good news even for first generation MacBookPro owners:

- 90% of Apple's Windows 7 drivers work on Windows 8. I'm still using Win7
  drivers on my 2010 MacBookPro and it all works.
- There's a comment trail on cafe-encounter from someone who successfully got Windows 8 working on a first generation MacBookPro:
  http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p1118/direct-download-of-bootcamp-drivers-further-help/comment-page-1#comment-5544

The approach was: (1) Run BootCamp and install Win7, then (2) one-by-one install the drivers for MacBookPro2,1 (which is the oldest supported model for Win7)